# How configurate the certificate of php 5.6 in SmtpTransport of ZEND 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-mail

Using phpMailer the config is that (it is working):

```
   $mail->SMTPOptions = array (
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer'  => true,
        'verify_depth' => 3,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'peer_name' => 'smtp.rei.unicamp.br',
        'cafile' => '/var/www/apache/conf/certs/cadeia-completa-globalsign.pem',
    )
```

My old configuration of Smtp are (it is working in php versions before 5.6):

```
$options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
            'name' => $name,
            'host' => $host,
            'port' => 587,
            'connection_class'  => 'plain',
            'connection_config' => array(
                            'username' => 'test',
                            'password' => 'test123',
                            'ssl'      => 'tls',
            ),
```

Anyone knows how I put the first configuration on the SmtpOptions of Zend 2?

Thank you!!

Comment: I'd love to know as well.